# z-index bug on IE7, usual workaround unapplicable

Tags: internet-explorer-7, popup, z-index, css-position

my problem is the following:
I've got a grid of containers. When you hover one of them, a child element(absolutely positioned) is popping up. I gave this child element a z-index of 100, and everthing works fine. Except in IE7, where img-elements of the parent container lie above the popup.
Now I know that you can give the parent element a higher z-index than the popup to avoid this problem. In my grid layout, this doesn't work, because there are several parent-container over which the popup is floating. Applying this technique, every container lies in front of the popup, even in modern browsers.
Here is a simple sketch of the situatuion:

[image: z-index IE7 problem]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Setting a z-index on a div is actually supposed to create a stacking context, not simply bring the div, it's applied to, above another.. so while I do think IE7 didn't get it quite right, (surprise!)

I think it would be better to make the oner divs the ones that create the start of the stack by setting the z-index on them, and what you want it for the first oner to have a higher z-index than the second

Comment: I did exactly as you said, but did'nt achieve any results. I set the parent(brighter) elements with a lower z-index than the children, but this way the children are in the back, even in modern browsers.